# why don't I get index returns from list comprehension checking truth values?

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a numpy array with numeric values, floats to be exact and NaNs:

```
In [1]: type(myarray)
Out[1]: numpy.ndarray
```

now I want to check where there are NaNs in this array so I try:

```
nan_idx = [idx for idx, tf in enumerate(myarray) if not bool(tf)]
```

However this returns an empty list, but when I try:

```
np.where(pd.isnull(mayarray))[0]
```

I do get as output the index of each NaN

Why doesn't the first attempt produce any results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your first snippet doesn't work is that `bool(float)` does not check for NaNs:

```
>>> float('NaN')
nan
>>> bool(float('NaN'))
True
>>> not bool(float('NaN'))
False
```

To check for NaNs, you could use `numpy.isnan` or the fact that a NaN doesn't compare equal to itself:

```
>>> numpy.isnan(float('NaN'))
True
>>> float('NaN') != float('NaN')
True
```